# UI-SELECT binding to controller.js in Array?

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

First of all, thank you for your reading.
I am new to the language.

I am trying to use UI-SELECT and bind the data to controller.js to save into database.

I know that UI-SELECT should be used with ng-model in "A.selected" way.

I searched for some help but couldn't find how to make the below code in array style to work.

[HTML with UI-Select]

```
<ui-select ng-model = "project_customer_company.selected" theme="bootstrap">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="">
    {{$select.selected.customer_company_name}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="customer in customers | filter: $select.search">
    <div ng-bind-html="customer.customer_company_name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    <div ng-bind-html="customer.customer_company_ceo | highlight: $select.search"></div>
  </ui-select-choices>
```

[Controller.js]

```
$scope.project_customer_company = {};

$http.post("../crud/projects_insert.php", {
  project_title : $scope.project_title,
  project_customer_company : $scope.project_customer_company // coming from <UI-SELECT>, and this has to be changed like in array style but how?
  })
```

I think I am almost there, but it is returning only "array" sign.

I know this might be easy, but I am lost for almost a whole day.

Any advice would be highly appreciated and hope this issue helps the others as well. :)

Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui-select` will return the `ng-model` as an object only not an array. You can use the `.` syntax as shown in the below example and access the variables needed.

```
  $scope.fetch = function() {
    alert($scope.project_customer_company.selected.customer_company_name);
    alert($scope.project_customer_company.selected.customer_company_ceo);
  }
```

In the above code, you can see that first we access the `selected` property of the object `$scope.project_customer_company`, then using another `.` we access the individual properties `customer_company_name` and `customer_company_ceo`

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Let me know if you face any issues!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Hope this helps the others who struggle with UI-SELECT binding! Have a good day!